# Open Container using Icon Buttons on Flutter

Tags: flutter, transition, iconbutton

Good morning/afternoon or evening. I'm a newbie learning Flutter and I want to use the OpenContainer transition on my app but I don't know how. Here is one of my Icon Buttons codes inside the app:

```
        Container(

          margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: <Color>[Color(0xff61A534), Color(0xff5bd3a4)])),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.eco_rounded),
            iconSize: 40.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, Transicao(widget: TelaCatalogo()));
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
            child: Text('Catálogo',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.greenAccent.shade200, fontSize: 16.0))),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [animations package](https://pub.dev/packages/animations). The `OpenContainer` widget provides a ready-made animation.

You just need to wrap your card/button with it, and provide a `closedBuilder` (which builds the button and calls `openContainer` when pressed) and an `openBuilder` (which builds the `TelaCatalogo` page).

```
      OpenContainer(
        transitionType: _transitionType,
        openBuilder: (BuildContext context, VoidCallback _) {
          return MyPage();
        },
        closedBuilder: (BuildContext context, VoidCallback openContainer) {
          return MyCard(onPressed: openContainer);
        },
      ),
```

Comment: All right, I really appreciate that, thanks mate.

Comment: Mate, I come here 1 and a half hour later to say that it works. Thanks a lot, I made it

Comment: Imagina, bom trabalho :)

Comment: E é brasileiro ainda hahahaha, tmj irmão, fica com Deus